# Cannot import Angular flex-layout in my feature module

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to use Angular flex-layout in one of my modules but I cannot make it work.
When I import flex-layout in app module it works just fine but only in the app component.
When I import flex-layout in another module it doesn't work at all. I don't get any errors, it just doesn't work.

My code:

```
// App module
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

.

```
// AppComponent HTML - WORKS
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
  <div fxFlex="30%">
    example
  </div>
</div>
```

.

```
// Other module
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

import { SomeRoutingModule } from './some-routing.module';
import { SomeComponent } from './pages/some-component/some-component.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [SomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    SomeRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class GameModule { }
```

.

```
// SomeComponent HTML - DOESN'T WORK
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
  <div fxFlex="30%">
    example
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any error appearing?

Comment: No, I've also tried importing and exporting it in every module, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing the GameModule in the AppModule under the imports.

But, I would recommend you to create a shared module and place the flex-layout there beacuse latest Angular versions support shared module and is considered as best practice. More instructions on how to create a shared module is as follows:
https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module

Comment: That worked, but I am not sure that it would lazy load my module now.

Comment: I edited the answer. Please do check the edited answer as well.